# Можно ли сделать так чтобы папка node_modules не устанавливалась локально в проекте?

Tags: npm

Папка node_modules дублируется во всех проектах. Там очень много папок и файлов и куча мусора. 
Скажем чтобы развернуть маленькое приложение на реакте или vue js мне приходится ждать 10-15 минут пока всё поставиться. И когда хожу по этим папкам то там много тормозов.

Вот я захожу в папку projects/lesson 1 и делаю там npm install. Он долго всё ставит и там появляется папка node_modules с кучей мусора (125 mb). 
projects/lesson 1/node_modules
projects/lesson 2/node_modules
projects/lesson 3/node_modules

Можно ли как то указывать чтобы этот мусор не скапливался в подпапках, а был где то глобально?

Comment: глобально версионность собъется для всего этого "мусора". тут как бы фишка как раз в том, чтобы проект был изолирован.

Comment: лучше всего глобально если он находится где-то в интернете. можете поискать на CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну если в node_modules это добавилось, то наверное это не мусор..  ,значит разработчик посчитал его нужным. ..если просто ты имеешь ввиду что одинаковые модули используются в многих приложениях  и их не ставить индивидуально а сделать общие для всех то тогда нужно поставить их глобально через `npm install module_name  -g` но в этом случае у тебя если в package.json будет содержать этот модуль, то при npm install   его все равно установит.

поэтому что бы сделать модуль глобальным и экономить место, нужно сразу его установить (как я выше написал), потом удалить его имя из package.json
 и потом только делать `npm install`

ну а вообще.. лучше  так не делать. скорее всего там будет у всех уроков почти одинаковые модули и просто менять содержимое папки,  а node_modules оставлять как есть.. npm install не качает заново те модули которые есть уже в node_nodules.
Надеюсь мое рассуждение будет понятно  и ответ будет полезен.

Comment: Это понятно. А есть альтернативы npm чтобы не скапливать гору мусора, Хочется чтобы в папке проекты были только файлы проекта и всё. А то если у меня будет 100 проектов то там же будет и куча лишних файлов лежать. 
Или это навечно зашито в архитектуру javascript и так будет всегда?

Comment: ну я ж написал все захе..ить  глобально . но тогда эта куча мусора будет  торчать в node . что не есть хорошо  как по безопасности так и  простоо некрасиво.    тем более как выше был комментарий , может быть проблема с версионностью.( она в js почти всегда есть) и глобально установленные модули могут быть для каких- то других  модулей слишком старыми или слишком новыми. короче это замкнутый круг.. все разворачивают как есть да и все. короче альтернативы нету.  хотя есть еще yarn, работает немного быстрее но от проблемы модулей в  node_modules  ты не уйдешь.